# How to fix cleartext traffic not permitted issue in Xiomi Redmi 3S with Android 6.0.1

Tags: android, android-manifest

When i am using URL with **http** then it shows an error "**CLEARTEXT communication to *(domain name)* not permitted by network security policy**" . I have tried **cleartextTrafficPermitted** = true in manifest.xml file but it is not compatible with payment gateway i use, which need cleartextTrafficPermitted = false. As it is API level 23 so, **networkSecurityConfig** = "@xml/network_security_config" doesn't work in it. I am using Retrofit as networking Library.

It is device specific issue Xiomi Redmi 3S, MIUI Global 10.2, Android version 6.0.1.

Any suggestion about this issue.

Comment: The error message clearly shows that the networkSecurityConfig is active. As you don't provide a custom on the system default networkSecurityConfig is used. Therefore provide your own networkSecurityConfig, it will be used if the device is running API23 or higher.

Comment: I have used networkSecurityConfig and it working for Android Pie, but not in my Redmi 3S device.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android 8: Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted)

Comment: It is different as Android 6.1, network file does't work, issue specific to Xiomi with MIUI Global 10.2 can you give any suggestion for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got solution by [medium post](https://medium.com/@imstudio/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted-73c1c9e3b803) , Code i used :

- Step 1: create file : res/xml/network_security_config.xml 
  Add code in this file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">Your URL(ex: 127.0.0.1)</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

- Step 2: Add line in AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        ...
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```